# Selenium: get_attribute one condition

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping a website and do have a solution, but I am sure there is a better one. I do not like the if-statement and think there could be a better one.

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome("....chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
 driver.get("https://www.transfermarkt.de/yannick-gerhardt/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/119277/saison//verein/0/liga/0/wettbewerb//pos/0/trainer_id/0/plus/1")
 verein = []
 bilder=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
 for b in bilder:
     if "tiny_wappen" in b.get_attribute('class'):
         verein.append(b.get_attribute('alt'))

 <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/wappen/tiny/21087.png? 
lm=1503056592" title="&nbsp;" alt="VfL Wolfsburg U17" class="tiny_wappen">
```

This is the output, which is all the clubs that the player played for.

```
 ['VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  'VfL Wolfsburg',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln',
  '1.FC Köln U19',
  '1.FC Köln II',
  '1.FC Köln U19',
  '1.FC Köln U19',
  '1.FC Köln U17',
  '1.FC Köln U17',
  '1.FC Köln U17']
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster and clean solution is to use Javascript:

```
 verein = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('img.tiny_wappen')].map(element => element.getAttribute('alt'));")
```

With pure selenium: `img` with `tiny_wappen` class

```
bilder=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.tiny_wappen")
for b in bilder:
     verein.append(b.get_attribute('alt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get required output with below one-liner:

```
verein = [img.get_attribute('alt') for img in driver.find_elements("css", ".tiny_wappen")]
```