# Selenium Python Storing id information in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to iterate through an unordered list  and collect the id information within each `<li>`

For instance,

```
<ul>
<li id = Example-info>...</li>
```

Is there a way I can store "Example-info" into a variable or a list

[image: I want to store the id= "string" information]

I have the following code

```
ids = []
resultSet = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[5]/ul')
ids = resultSet.find_element_by_tag_name('li')

for id in ids:
    print (id)
```

This consists of the xpath to the `<ul>` tag

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Complete Code here.
https://pastebin.com/zC8VeeUf

Comment: check this out [Python & Selenium - how do I find all element IDs on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244691/python-selenium-how-do-i-find-all-element-ids-on-a-page)

Comment: Please share html in text format starting from `//*[@id="mainContent"]` element

Comment: You can try this `ids = resultSet.find_element_by_tag_name('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close to being correct. You just have to call `find_elements` (notice the S) which creates a list of the children

Your print statement is also wrong

```
ids = []
resultSet = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[5]/ul')
ids = resultSet.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

for id in ids:
    print(id.get_attribute('id'))
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot im completely blanking out, another hint! :D PLEASE

Comment: @davidyeritsyan what do you mean? You can just get the ID from there an do with it what you need?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused with when you said to "call the find_elements (notice the S) which creates a list of the children:"

Comment: you are calling `find_element_by_tag_name` which returns the first element within `ul`. If you call `find_elements_by_tag_name` you get a list of all the elements within `ul` which are called its children.

Comment: I said notice the S just to differentiate between `find_element_by_tag_name` and `find_elements_by_tag_name`

Comment: oh LOL i feel like a complete moron you are the best :D

Comment: So I think I still get a issue with that solution, I'll update my post to show the error code

Comment: @davidyeritsyan I didn’t realize you needed help doing the whole thing... I updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Sorry i've been playing with selenium for 2 days I'll take note of what you did for future reference I appreciate your help

Comment: @davidyeritsyan did that work for you? Or do you been more for the formatting of the ids? I’m happy to help!

Comment: I'll be completely honest, I'm now getting an error, "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute', I thought maybe I should remove the quotes from the id.getAttribute(id) but that seems to give me the same error

Comment: @davidyeritsyan my bad, I used the java version of getAttribute instead of the python get_attribute

Comment: your fine I'm extremely greatful for all your help i'll try that out right now thank you so much again!

Comment: You are a god among men, Thank you again for all your help you, I'm sorry that I didn't understand some of the things you said, your the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript and get all id's in list in one line, my only complain is xpath you used `//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[5]/ul`. I'm pretty sure you can use much better selector:

```
#ids is a list 
ids = browser.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.left-panel li')].map(e => e.getAttribute('id'));")
```

Also you can find some solutions here: [Selenium: get_attribute one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131049/selenium-get-attribute-one-condition/52131185#52131185)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a much better selector, do you mean this #mainContent > div.left-panel > div > div.result-list > ul

Comment: @davidyeritsyan `#mainContent > div.left-panel > div > div.result-list > ul` for selector probably you can avoid some parts and make it simple and more stable like  `.left-panel .result-list li` or `.result-list li`. For future, if you share html code as text you can get some useful examples how to locate elements from the community

Comment: http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=schoolId&schoolName=California+State+University%2C+Northridge&schoolID=163&queryoption=TEACHER          This is the link :) on the left panel it shows the professor names and when I  do "inspect" on the professor name is where you can locate the list

Comment: Try javascript in my answer to get all id in one line with simple css selector

Comment: What the problem? You want get professor names and ids?